# Получить ссылку на картинку python

Tags: python

https://www.cian.ru/sale/flat/230946309/ в этом объявлении есть фото.Нужно получить ссылки на эти фото. Делал post запрос, все равно выдает none. Подскажите, что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for url in list_url:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="html.parser")
    images = []
    for img in soup.findAll('img'):
        images.append(img.get('src'))

    print(images)
```